# Что необходимо исправить в коде или дописать?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть адаптивное меню, которое отлично работает, за исключением подменю (Квартиры, VIP) где пункт подменю раскрывается по hover, я же хочу сделать с помощью js события click. Но почему-то не выходит... Кто может помочь или подсказать что я сделал не правильно в коде, или что не написал? Короче где тупанул? Спасибо.

```
    <div id="topMenu" class="pagemenucontainer_open"></div>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

$("#topMenu").click(function(){
    $("#pagemenucontainer").slideToggle(500);
});

var count = 0;

$("#mli_open").parent(".mli_toggle").parent(".mli").click(function(){

    count += 1;

if (count==1) {
    //$(this).children("a").removeAttr("href");
}
else {
    //$(this).children("a").attr("href", "<?php echo $category['href']; ?>");
    //$(this).children("a").attr("href", "<?php if($category){ echo $category['href'];} ?>");
}
    // $(".mli>a").removeAttr("href");
    //$('.mli>.mli_toggle').slideToggle(500);
    //$(this).addClass("mli_a");
});

});
```

также приведу пример кода PHP, который отвечает за меню:

```
    <div id="pagemenucontainer" style=" background-color: #FFF; padding- bottom: 1px; margin-bottom: 10px;">

    <div class="container">
    <?php if ($categories) { ?>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a></li>

        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>

        <li class="mli" ><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
         <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>

         <div class="mli_toggle"> 

        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>

        <ul id="mli_open">

        <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
        <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
        <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>

       </ul>
     <?php } ?>
  </div>

  <?php } ?>
</li>
<?php } ?>
<li><a href="http://royal-apartment.kiev.ua/index.php?route=information/contact">Инфо</a></li>
```

Ссылка на сам [проект](http://royal-apartment.kiev.ua/) (сразу сообщаю что ПКМ не работает, смотреть только через консоль разработчика в браузере.)

код CSS (меню)

```
    /* menu */
    #menu {
       height: 37px;
       padding: 0px 5px;
       margin-bottom: 7px;
       margin-left: 25px;
    }
    #menu ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #menu > ul > li {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      z-index: 20;
      padding: 6px 5px 5px 0px;
     }
     #menu > ul > li:hover {
     }
     #menu > ul > li > a {
       font-size: 16px;
       color: #2c3e50;
       border-right: 1px solid #2c3e50;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       display: block;
       padding: 6px 15px;
       margin-bottom: 5px;
       z-index: 6;
       position: relative;
     }
     #menu > ul > li:last-child > a, #menu > ul > li:last-child:hover > a {
       border-right: none;
     }
     #menu > ul > li:hover > a {
       color: #e15153;
       text-decoration: underline;
       border-right: 1px solid #e15153;
     }
     #menu > ul > li > div {
       display: none;
       background: #FFFFFF;
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 5;
       padding: 5px;
       border: 1px solid #000000;
       -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
       -khtml-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
       border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
       background: url('../image/menu.png');
      }
      #menu > ul > li:hover > div {
       display: table;
      }
      #menu > ul > li > div > ul {
       display: table-cell;
      }
      #menu > ul > li ul + ul {
       padding-left: 20px;
      }
      #menu > ul > li ul > li > a {
       text-decoration: none;
       padding: 4px;
       color: #FFFFFF;
       display: block;
       white-space: nowrap;
       min-width: 120px;
      }
      #menu > ul > li ul > li > a:hover {
       background: #000000;
      }
     #menu > ul > li > div > ul > li > a {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      padding-left: 10px;
     }

     @media screen and (max-width: 500px)
     #menu > ul > li > div {
      position: relative;
      width: 95%;
      margin-left: 1% !important;
      background: #919191 !important;
      border: 1px solid #919191;
     }
```

Comment: я как понимаю, то в js дописать еще .slideToggle('') только вот на какое событие?

Comment: css показать и переписать не хочется?

Comment: а что в css переписать именно? показать могу

Comment: Вам же нужно убрать селектор :hover. А следующее решить как будете решать проблему, либо создадите класс, который будете добавлять к вашему элементу (<li>) при нажатии и убирать при повторном нажатии. Либо же полностью обойдетесь функционалом JQuery (например show и hide).

Comment: выложил код CSS, но я там не вижу какой hover влияет на ситуацию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите из css:

```
#menu > ul > li:hover > div {
       display: table;
      }
```

В js допишите:

```
<script>
$( "li.mli" ).click(function() {
  $(this).children('div').toggle();
});
</script>
```

Учитывайте скрипт должен быть после инициализации страницы (задействованых элементов).

Comment: то есть после моего скрипта?

Comment: @zorro js должен быть либо после объявления всех элементов с которыми он работает или еще лучше в блоке: `$( document ).ready(function() {
    ...
});`

Comment: все отлично, спасибо, только перед children лишняя точка.

Comment: и еще такой вопрос, меню теперь закрывается само по себе... в чем может быть дело, и не кликабельны пункты подменю

Comment: @zorro, спасибо, точку поправил. Проверьте консоль ошибок js.
Еще как вариант вам стоит разобраться со средой в которой работаете. Это какая то CMS? Могут быть конфликты с родным js.

Comment: это OpenCart, возможно и конфликты, здесь кода туча, а консоль выдает вот такое, но не ошибкой, Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://royal-apartment.kiev.ua/".
jquery.cycle.js:11 terminating; too few slides: 0

Answer (score 0):

Ну еще вот так можно, совсем нормально получилось:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "li.mli>a" ).click(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).parent().find('.mli_toggle').length) {
            $(this).parent().children('div').toggle();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```